# How to check a textInput on emptiness

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need your help. I want to check my textInput for an empty filed, when I am pressing a button. Because now my application can route user to target page with empty fields. So I need to check this fields on emptyness. But I don't know how to do it. I will be very glad, if you help me.

This is my component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import { MyButton, ErrorMessage } from '../uikit'
import { FormStyle, InputStyle } from '../constants/styles'
import { LOG_IN } from '../routes'

export class SignIn extends Component {
    
    state = {
        isValidPasword: true,
        isEqual: true,
        isValidMail: true,
        currentPassword: ''
    }

    isEnoughSymbols = (text) => {
        if (text.trim().length < 8) {
            this.setState({ isValidPasword: false })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ currentPassword: text, isValidPasword: true })
        }
    }

    isMatch = (text) => {
        if (text != this.state.currentPassword) {
            this.setState({ isEqual: false })
        }
    }

    isMail = (text) => {
        const pattern = /\b[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b/i
        let res = text.search(pattern)

        res == -1 ? this.setState({ isValidMail: false }) : this.setState({ isValidMail: true })
    }

    render() {
        const { mainContainer, buttons } = FormStyle
        const { container, text } = InputStyle
        const { isValidPasword, isEqual, isValidMail, currentPassword } = this.state

        return (
            <View style={mainContainer}>

                <View style={container}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={text}
                        placeholder={'Email'}
                        onEndEditing={(e) => this.isMail(e.nativeEvent.text)}
                    >
                    </TextInput>
                    {
                        isValidMail ? null : <ErrorMessage errorText={'Invalid email!'} />
                    }
                </View>

                <View style={container}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={text}
                        placeholder={'Password'}
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        onEndEditing={(e) => this.isEnoughSymbols(e.nativeEvent.text)}
                    >
                    </TextInput>
                    {
                        isValidPasword ? null : <ErrorMessage errorText={'Password must have at least 8 symbols!'} />
                    }
                </View>

                <View style={container}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={text}
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        placeholder={'Confirm password'}
                    >
                    </TextInput>
                    {
                        isEqual ? null : <ErrorMessage errorText={'Passwords not matching'} />
                    }
                </View>

                <View style={buttons}>
                    <MyButton
                        name={'confirm'.toUpperCase()}
                        onPress={() => (isEqual && isValidMail && isValidPasword) ? this.props.navigation.navigate(LOG_IN) : alert('Your data is wrong!')} />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value of the text input using state.

E.g.

```
state = {
        /// rest of state
        textValue: ""
    }
```

In the TextInput component add a function to set the state onChange, so the `textValue` changes when the user types, e.g. `(e) => this.setState({ textValue: e.nativeEvent.text })`

Then you can check if the input is empty with a function that checks for the state value, like `if(this.textValue === "")` and then handle the empty vs. not-empty condition.

Comment: What is the difference beetween e.target.value and e.nativeEvent.text?

Comment: @Vladimir Oh, e.target.value is for web and e.nativeEvent.text is for mobile. On the React Native docs I looked at the onChange event and it responds with the nativeEvent obj, while onChange in React responds with target or currentTarget. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Better way you can make function like this to check empty spaces, Blank value and text length.

```
function isEmpty(isFieldEmpty) {
    isFieldEmpty = isFieldEmpty.trim()
    if (!isFieldEmpty || isFieldEmpty == "" || isFieldEmpty.length <= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```